# Two Failover Nodes With the Same Disks, Is it Ok to Remove the Old Node?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, failovercluster

Recently we've had a file server recreated with the same disks. The new server `newfs1` was created with the same exact disks, same path, same disk; as the old file server `oldfs1`.

Both servers are in the Failover Cluster Manager. The problem comes in with the `oldfs1` server--this server is creating alerts constantly because it is in a failed state in the Cluster Manager. I think the solution is to remove the node, but I'm not 100% sure that the disks will stay intact, or if there would be any issues.

Is it safe to `right-click>remove` the `oldfs1` node from the cluster manager?

Is there a better way to handle getting rid of the `oldfs1` node from cluster manager?

I am also open to any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to successfully `right click>remove` on the `oldfs1` node in the cluster manager. The `oldfs1` server still existed in the Hyper-v manager after removing.